# Renderizar componentes Razor en MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, .net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-mvc

Estoy intentando renderizar componentes Razor en una app MVC para poder reutilizar código, principalmente mi app esta es en .Net Core 3.1 pero la cambie a 5 para poder utilizar Componentes y ver si era viable el cambio.

El problema es que el componente inicia pero el onclick de InncrementCount no funciona, no hace la llamada al servidor ni renderiza el componente. En la consola del navegador me aparece esto. Nose si es correcto o algo esta mal.

```
[2022-09-09T18:17:09.546Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'https://localhost:44341/_blazor'.
blazor.server.js:1 
[2022-09-09T18:17:10.290Z] Information: WebSocket connected to wss://localhost:44341/_blazor?id=jJqHkzkiCwhwnLo91ny5kw.
```

Esto encontré en internet.

```
    <p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click</button>

@code {
    public int currentCount { get; set; } = 0;

    public void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

El componente se inicia porque he usado el override OnInitialized y entra en el método.

Este es el StartUp.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
            });
            //services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=InicioDeSesion}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            });
            
        }
```

Archivo _Imports.razor creado por mi (Vi que esta "@using WebStoreApplication_Administracion.Views" se reemplaza por Shared en vez de View, pero no tengo Shared a ese nivel de Carpetas. )

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization
@using Microsoft.JSInterop

@using WebStoreApplication_Administracion
@using WebStoreApplication_Administracion.Views
```

Y en el _Layout.cshtml tengo esto

```
<base href="~/"/>
<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

Comment: y cual es la pregunta, error y/o problema?

Comment: Evita confundir Blazor con Razor MVC y Razor Pages. Son enfoques diferentes.

Comment: No hace la llamada al onclick, con lo cual no esta haciendo la llamada al servidor @David081.

Comment: Edita la pregunta e incluye ese detalle. Recomendaciones para armar preguntas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Prueba colocar app.MapBlazorHub(); en la función configure del startup

Comment: @Yussef esta disponible en el endpoints.MapBlazorHub(); solamente, no en el app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final todo lo que hice estaba bien lo unico para corregir es que la etiqueta

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

Debe estar al final del _Layout.cshtml antes del cierre del body y html

Comment: Interesante, entonces, técnicamente puede mezclarse Razor Pages y Blazor y va a funcionar. Bien jugado :D